# can't handle portlet action phase

Tags: controller, liferay, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I have a basic Liferay portlet and use Spring MVC. I have only one controller for VIEW mode of portlet and only one form. When I submit the form, action phase is not handled.

**GraphViewController.java**

```
package graphui;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.bind.annotation.ActionMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.bind.annotation.RenderMapping;

/**
 *
 * Controller for VIEW mode of portlet.
 */
@Controller("graphViewController")
@RequestMapping(value = "VIEW")
public class GraphViewController{

    private static final String MODEL_KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String MODEL_KEY_AGE = "age";
    private static final String MODEL_KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private Person repository = new Person("pete", 33, "pete@pete.com");
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GraphViewController.class);

    @ActionMapping(GraphUIConstants.SUBMIT_FORM)
    public void handleActionRequest(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)throws Exception {

            logger.info("action phase executed");

            if (request.getParameter("name") != null)
                repository.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
            if (request.getParameter("age") != null)
                repository.setAge(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age")));
            if (request.getParameter("email") != null)
                repository.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));

    }

    @RenderMapping
    public ModelAndView handleRenderRequest(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response, ModelMap model) {

      logger.info("render phase executed");  

      model.addAttribute(MODEL_KEY_NAME, gson.toJson(repository.getName()));
      model.addAttribute(MODEL_KEY_AGE, gson.toJson(repository.getAge()));
      model.addAttribute(MODEL_KEY_EMAIL, gson.toJson(repository.getEmail()));
      return new ModelAndView("index", model);
    }

}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="graphui.GraphUIConstants" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<portlet:actionURL name="<%= GraphUIConstants.SUBMIT_FORM %>" var="submitForm" />

<div>
    <form id="myForm" action="${submitForm}" method="post">

        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="name">Name:</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input name="name" id="name" class="field-required" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="age">Age:</label>
          <div class="controls">
              <input name="age" id="age" class="field-required field-digits" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="email">E-mail:</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input name="email" id="email" class="field-required field-email" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>

        <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Reset">

    </form>

    <ul>
        <li>${name};</li>
        <li>${age};</li>
        <li>${email};</li>
    </ul>  

</div>
```

**Person.java**

```
package graphui;


public class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String email;

    public Person(String name, int age, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

**GraphUIConstants.java**

```
package graphui;


public class GraphUIConstants {

    public static final String SUBMIT_FORM = "submitForm";

}
```

**GraphUI-portlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="graphui" />

   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
      <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
   </bean>

   <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.GsonHttpMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/> 
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/> 

   <!-- Spring MVC Message Source -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true"/>
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>content.graph</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does "action phase is not handled" mean?
It goes to render phase directly? Or do you have a kind of Exception in your log?

Otherwhise it is impossible to understand the cause...
At first look everithing seem ok... by the way, did you try to modify in this way your actionUrl?

```
<portlet:actionURL var="submitForm">
    <portlet:param name="action" value="validateRequest"></portlet:param>
</portlet:actionURL>
```

And, before, are you importing in your JSP the portlet taglib?

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to add taglib portlet